# How to delete multiple lines in multiple files

Tags: emeditor

I need to edit large number of files, the editing will be to remove lines that I need to find, since the files are more than 3000, my question is can I search through the files all at once? then delete all the results in all the files also at once? my search will be based on key words and sentences.
Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your question with an example.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.